# book recommendations for further learning about dynamical system and bifurcation

Tags: dynamical-systems, bifurcation

I have read the book "Introduction to Applied Nonlinear Dynamical Systems and Chaos"by Stephen Wiggins.Could someone recommend books on dynamical systems and bifurcation theory for further learning?

Answer (score 5):

The Wiggins book is pretty hard to beat if you liked it.

Here are some recommendations to peruse online and see if they suit your needs. I like all three for different reasons and believe these are all well received generally.

- Nonlinear Dynamics and Chaos, S.H. Strogatz
- Dynamics and Bifurcations, J. Hale and H. Kocak
- An Introduction to Dynamical Systems, D.K. Arrowsmith and C.M. place

Another book that is not as popular and different (precisely why I have it) is:

- Perspectives of Nonlinear Dynamics, E.A. Jackson

There are many other books on the matter out there. For example (I do not own this book, but have perused it many times and it has a wonderful problem set).

- Differential Equations, Dynamical Systems, and an Introduction to Chaos, , M. W. Hirsch, S. Smale (Author), R.L. Devaney

Comment: You are certainly the one to ask!

Comment: I sure will. Thanks ;-)

Comment: @amWhy Clearly, according to your comment, you have no clue what kind of books are appropriate to read after studying the book by Wiggins in the original post, the same way obviously as Amzoti, whose usual literature advice is quite close to a request, e.g., "dynamical systems" on Amazon.com. So here is my question: What is the point to upvote answers in which you cannot judge the content?